# html element stretch to remaining view port height

Tags: css, viewport

So I am trying to do that section which is below navigation would automatically fill the remaining view-port height. Section contains one centered div and background picture. At the bottom there is a button which on click scrolls down full view-port height. Navigation is all bootstrap but I will add it here in case you need more details:

```html
<body>
    <a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="images/main.png" class="d-inline-block align-top navImg" alt="UAB Betono zona">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav navItems">
                <li class="nav-item"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown"> 
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link2
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink"> 
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item1</a> 
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item2</a> 
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item3</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item4</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item5</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link4</a> 
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> 
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link5</a> 
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <section class="mainSection">
        <div class="logoWrap">
            <h1>
              <span class="hFirst">Text1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
              <span class="hSecond">Text2</span>
             </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="scrollDown"> 
            <a href="#" class="next-viewport-down"><span></span>down</a>
        </div>
    </section>
```

As for a temporary solution I'm using **height: 91vh**, but its not a good option as different devices will display it differently. CCS of the section:

```css
section.mainSection {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    height: 91vh;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(images/Main3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

div.logoWrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.logoWrap .hFirst {
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 4rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
}

div.logoWrap .hSecond {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 4rem;
}
```

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Please provide your full code as part of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also note that a `<main>` tag exists in HTML5, which could replace your `section.mainSection`.

Comment: Are you saying that i should paste whole bootstrap 4 css here? :)

Comment: No but the code you have provided is not sufficient to have a proper grasp of the visual output. We need to be able to replicate it to understand it and help you.

Comment: If your navigation is in normal flow (not absolute/fixed or anything like that), then using flexbox should get you there quite easily. Use body as the flex container, give it a min-height of 100vh, and make the section auto-grow via its flex property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use flexbox to fill up available space, see the code below (top of CSS is new, the rest is unchanged):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.navbar {
  flex: 0;
}

.mainSection {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

/* Your code below is unchanged */

section.mainSection {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(images/Main3.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

div.logoWrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div.logoWrap .hFirst {
    font-weight: 600;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
    line-height: 4rem;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: auto;
}

div.logoWrap .hSecond {
    position: relative;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="javascript:" id="return-to-top"><i class="icon-chevron-up"></i></a>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="images/main.png" class="d-inline-block align-top navImg" alt="UAB Betono zona">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> 
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> 
          </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav navItems">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Link2
                      </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item1</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item2</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item3</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item4</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Item5</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link3</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link4</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link5</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="mainSection">
    <div class="logoWrap">
      <h1>
        <span class="hFirst">Text1</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="hSecond">Text2</span>
      </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="scrollDown">
      <a href="#" class="next-viewport-down"><span></span>down</a>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks a lot.